# Unit SysUtils was compiled with a different version of SysConst.SMonitorLockException when trying to compile project in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm trying to compile a project and I'm getting this error.

The error occurs in a RemObjects source file, but I think it doesn't have anything to do with RemObjects.

Anyway this error is too generic, and I don't quite get why it happens, so how can I solve it?

Comment: You should translate resourcestrings by linking in new resources, not by modifying the units directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that we translated the unit SysConsts and the Interface changed, removing that unit solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you mix libraries. You are probably using a (third-party) library that is compiled with a different version. Try to get the latest version, or recompile if you have the source.

If the problem persists, try to get a minimal subset of the project to find the offending unit / dcu file.